# 'Next' button is not being clicked (Selenium, Python, Chromedriver)

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape a website that has a few pages. I wanted to loop clicking on the "Next" button and scraping until the button is no longer available but I think I've failed. The button is found on the website (I've checked that by locating it and extracting its html) but the clicking and extracting later on seems not to be working.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the webpage
url = 'https://www.screwfix.com/c/tools/drills/cat830704?page_size=100'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)

# Find elements using xpath
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container-main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]')

# Get and print the text attribute of each element
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    
# Locate next button and print its HTML
next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container-main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/nav/button[2]')
print(next_button.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

# Iterate through pages using "Next" button
while True:
    try:
        next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container-main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/nav/button[2]')
        next_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)  # Wait for page to load
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container-main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]')
        for element in elements:
            print(element.text)
    except:
        break  # Exit loop if "Next" button is not found

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

It scrapes one page of products, then Next button's HTML and nothing else. I've expected 4 pages of products.

Comment: maybe you can add wait until
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="container-main"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]'))
        )`